# Cycles nodes for viewing angle/making parts of mesh invisible

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, camera

I'm trying to create a material that causes parts of a mesh to become invisible when the camera view is past a certain angle.

[EDIT: New example including a node setup]

For example, when viewing a plane with this material, I want to make the parts outside of a central cone disappear. The following Suzanne is being viewed by the camera. The "cone" is 1/2 the viewport and she is completely inside it:

[image: Suzanne completely inside the viewing cone]

When I zoom in, parts of Suzanne that are outside the "cone" disappear. Here is the material view:
[image: Suzanne partly inside the viewing cone/material view]

Here is the render view:

[image: Suzanne partly inside the viewing cone/render view]
This is my current node setup:

[image: Node setup]

This setup uses the camera view vector and computes the distance from the center to the shading point (sqrt(x**2+y**2)).

Is this a good way to go?

Comment: Does the facing output form the layer weight node (found under input) provide what you are looking for?

Comment: Do a search for "Fresnel".

Comment: I don't think either the layer weight node or fresnel technique are what I'm looking for. The effect I want does not depend on the mesh normals. It only depends on whether a part of the mesh is inside or outside a virtual cone whose apex is at the camera position.